# How to change the URL in an Edge tab with Powershell

Tags: powershell, web, url, tabs, fullscreen

I am using Powershell and MS Edge. This is on a routine where we are changing a web page every minute. However I cannot figure out how to change the address of the current tab to reflect the new address so the routine is creating lots of new tabs.

Currently I am using "Start-Process" to display the URL which creates a new tab every minute. To prevent tab build up every 10 minutes all tabs are closed and we start again. This also has the effect of putting the "Restore Pages" dialog on the screen. Its clunky but it works.
The addresses in the variable $Filename are https which open easily in a web browser.

The question is how to display https://www.bing.com then change it to display https://www.google.com without closing the browser or opening a new tab using Powershell.

```
 $Count++
    if ($Count -ge 10) { 
        Stop-Process -name msedge 
        $Count = 1
     }

    if ($Count -eq 1) {
    Start-Process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" -ArgumentList $Filename,"--start-fullscreen" }  
    if ($Count -gt 1) {
    Start-Process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" $Filename
```

Comment: Try the Ms edge driver for some more complicated automation: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/.

Comment: Start MS Edge using a local HTML page where you control the JavaScript that runs within it.  Then, everyone 10 minutes, your JavaScript will load a different URL in a target (named) tab.  It simplifies the PowerShell (1-liner?), and you'll have full control over the URLs and timings with JavaScript running inside your local HTML page.